# Problems with echo into bluetooth tty device MacOS?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, bluetooth, tty

Background:

I want to send data to a RN42 bluetooth module using bluetooth on my computer.

When I try to

```
echo -ne "hi" > /dev/tty.MyDevice-RNI-SPP
```

I cannot get anything out of my bluetooth module. I hooked it up to an oscilloscope and I don't see anything. However, when I enter "screen" and start typing nonsense I see data being sent out on the oscilloscope.

Also, if I call

```
system((std::string("echo -ne \"") + printstr + std::string("\" > ") + directory).c_str());
```

in a C++ program in the exact same directory, I just get an "Operation not permitted"

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `directory`?

Comment: Why are you using `echo` from a C++ program? Why not just open it as a file in C++ and then write to it with `<<`?

Comment: @Barmar directory is just a string with the directory path. I didn't think of opening it up as a file and using <<. Do you know how I would do that?

Comment: @Barmar But even echoing in terminal is impossible to the file, even though screen works. I don't know why, when I just need to send data over to the bluetooth without reading.

Comment: `ofstream device(directory); device << "hi\n";`

Comment: What does `screen` have to do with it? How are you interacting with the device using `screen`?

Comment: @Barmar Well screen let's me establish a serial connection like putty. I just do: screen /dev/tty.MyDevice-RNI-SPP which let's me send and receive data in the terminal

Comment: @Barmar I just tried it with your suggestion. Nothing was sent over.

Comment: @Barmar The file failed to open

Comment: Does `stty -a -f /dev/tty.MyDevice-RNI-SPP` work from the terminal?

Comment: @Barmar Yes it spewed a lot of data:

Comment: Stuff Like this: speed 9600 baud; 0 rows; 0 columns;
lflags: -icanon -isig -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoke -echonl
 -echoctl -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho -pendin
 -nokerninfo -extproc

Comment: @Barmar Furthermore, open() from termios.h isn't working either

Comment: I'm not sure why `screen` and `stty` are able to open it, but you can't open it from the shell or C++. Are you still in `screen` when you try the `echo`? `screen` opens the terminal in exclusive mode, which will prevent other processes from opening it.

Comment: @Barmar No i'm not in screen when I do echo.

Comment: @Barmar So this is what I just did. I connected the module serially to my computer and also connected it bluetooth to my computer. I can screen into both and see output on both sides. However, when I try to do file open for the serial port, it just gets stucks

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I don't think it's the problem, but I wouldn't recommend using `echo` for this. On MacOS, the shell's builtin implementation will respond to `echo -ne "hi"` with just "hi" (no newline) as expected, but /bin/echo will instead print "-ne hi" followed by a newline. Use `printf` instead, it's much more predictable (but more complicated to use correctly).